# wso2 eclipse server in status [starting] forever

Tags: eclipse, wso2, wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

I am trying to start/stop WSO2 ESB local server from Developer studio (based on kepler), but the server status will stay [Starting] forever (even after the server started successfully as evidenced by the console and wso2carbon.log).

This is a problem, as it prevents me from deploying car files from within eclipse (eclipse waiting for server to finish starting), and even eclipse will shut the server down after the timeout elapses.

How can I persuade eclipse that the server started already?
Is it possible to configure the server state detection mechanism somehow?

WSO2 ESB 4.8.0
Developer studio: developer-studio-eclipse-jee-kepler-linux-gtk-x86_64-3.6.0.zip (same with juno)
Platform: Ubuntu 13.10

I will be thankful for any suggestions

Comment: Well, I still dont know what was going on, but I solved the problem by re-setting the Proxy settings in Eclipse. (Apparently the new eclipse instance (DevStudio) was getting the proxy information (incorrect) from some previous (inactive) eclipse instance settings). Dont ask me how, I have no idea  :)