# wso2-esb-5.0.0 server not getting started via Developer Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 developer studio - Luna version in Windows 10. I added a carbon server instance using developer studio and it got added successfully. It is not getting started and stays at 'Preparing launch delegate' as shown in the image.

[image: screen shot]

This link didn't help me: [wso2 eclipse server in status [starting] forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534368/wso2-eclipse-server-in-status-starting-forever)

Comment: To isolate the problem, have you tried starting the server from outside the developer studio? (using ESB_INSTALL_DIRECTORY/bin/wso2server.bat on windows)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. it also hangs without any error. 
F:\software\wso2\wso2esb-5.0.0\bin>wso2server.bat
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to F:\software\jdk1.8.0_141
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to F:\software\wso2\wso2esb-5.0.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: Are you running this inside a VM? Tried running as administrator?

Comment: I run this in a laptop, not a VM. I tried as admin. still no luck. There is no log showing any error. If I use the gitbash and run  the wso2server.sh (not the bat file), it works. Then the problem is that I can't use developer studio directly to run the server though I can manage connecting to that with 'wso2 carbon remote server' option from eclipse.